Code coverage for catch block
Trying to get to 100% code coverage - can't seem to cover the "catch" line:
@HttpPost
global static LeadResponse getLeadByName(LeadRequest leadRequest) {

    LeadResponse response = new LeadResponse(0, '');
    if (leadRequest.names == null || leadRequest.names.isEmpty()) {
        response.statusCode = 400;
        response.message = 'ambiguous request or payload unrecognized';
    } else {
        try {
            // default values in event of failure:
            response.statusCode = 500;
            response.message = 'Error encountered searching for accounts';

            // make the request
            List<Lead> leads = LeadSelector.getLeadByNames(leadRequest.names);
            if (leads == null || leads.isEmpty()) {
                response.statusCode = 404;
                response.message = 'No matching leads found';
            } else {
                response.statusCode = 200;
                response.message = 'Leads retrieved: ' + leads.size();
                response.leads = leads;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { // not covered :(
            // some other failure condition querying leads
        }
    }
    return response;
}

global class LeadRequest {
    public List<String> names;
}

global class LeadResponse {
    public Integer statusCode;
    public String message;
    public List<Lead> leads;

    public LeadResponse(Integer statusCode, String message) {
        this(statusCode, message, new List<Lead>());
    }

    public LeadResponse(Integer statusCode, String message, List<Lead> leads) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.message = message;
        this.leads = leads;
    }
}

Thanks for any guidance here.  Let me know if you need my test class or "LeadSelector" class as well.

100% coverage isn't as important as making sure you have a good number of tests that stress various scenarios (both positive and negative) and have proper assertions (you can get coverage for a method that returns 5 when you tell it "do 2+2". It's the assertions that protect you from bad results/improper implementations).

Also, it doesn't look to me like anything in your try block could possibly throw an exception. If you have a "pokemon catch" (catch(Exception e), cuz you're trying to catch 'em all instead of knowing what exceptions you could run into), that's a general sign that there shouldn't be a try/catch at all.

selectors should always return collections (even empty collections), never null.  If you used a factory pattern to get the selector object, you could dependency inject a mock selector at test time and, using apexmocks or similar, have that mock selector thrown an exception

When code is impossible to cover, it indicates one of two conditions. The first condition is that the code is unreachable. In other words, there's no logical way to reach that line of code. The other condition is that the unit test simply can't recreate the conditions necessary to cover the code. For example, maybe you're trying to cover some UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW errors, which can be challenging to emulate in a unit test.
In your specific case, you've covered every single possible scenario ahead of time by checking if leadRequest.names is valid or not. However, you do have a NullPointerException lurking in your code that's not covered by the try-catch block:
// What if leadRequest itself is null...?
if (leadRequest.names == null || leadRequest.names.isEmpty()) {

Aside from that, the code covered by the try-catch block doesn't have any inherent paths to throw any kind of exception, so the try-catch block is actually useless. If LeadSelector.getLeadByNames can throw an exception, that indicates you probably have a logic bug in that method. It should ever only return a List<Lead> object.
It's generally a bad practice to return null values. Also, as I've stated in another answer, you should never have to check for null and an empty list. Every function you write should return a consistent value, either null or an empty list, and as I just mentioned, null is a terrible idea, as it always makes code more complicated unnecessarily. Of course, there are times when you do need to return null (e.g. a Visualforce action function that may or may not redirect), but those are edge cases.
Note that my reason for mentioning that you should avoid null is that null, by definition, is an unknown value, while an empty list, or other "zero" data type is a known value that is empty. It's the difference between saying "we don't know if something exists" and "we know nothing exists."
In your specific case, remove the try-catch block. In the future, think about the possible states your data can be in before using try-catch blocks, and write unit tests to verify that an exception can be thrown. If you can't make an exception throw, then don't use a try-catch block, because it's likely impossible to cover.

Thanks - I had in mind the unlikely scenario of a database timeout error, (I did reduce my example to keep things simple and get at the crux of  the question) or some other catastrophic failure, e.g., it happens to fire during a SF maintenance window, or other such untestable condition.  I'll remove the catch block - thanks!

@PeterJaenicke indeed. If there were such a failure, you wouldn't be able to catch it anyways, so the try-catch is definitely not needed here.
